# How do I replace a string with a newline using a bash script and sed?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have the following input:

```
Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4@@ Value5|Value6|Value7|Value8@@ Value9|etc...
```

In my bash script I would like to replace the `@@`  with a newline. I have tried various things with sed but I'm not having any luck:

```
line=$(echo ${x} | sed -e $'s/@@ /\\\n/g')
```

Ultimately I need to parse this whole input into rows and values.  Maybe I am going about it wrong.  I was planning to replace the `@@`  with newlines and then loop through the input with setting `IFS='|'` to split up the values.  If there is a better way please tell me, I am still a beginner with shell scripting.

Comment: a `gnu` sed of recentish version should work with `...|sed 's/@@ /\n/g'`.. . Good luck.

Comment: awk with RS="@@ " and FS="|"

Answer (score 13):

Using pure BASH string manipulation:

```
eol=$'\n'
line="${line//@@ /$eol}"

echo "$line"
Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4
Value5|Value6|Value7|Value8
Value9|etc...
```

Or else do it in **single step**:

```bash
line="${line//@@ /$'\n'}"
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work...it did not replace the "@@ " at all `line="${x//@@ /$eol}"`

Comment: @odinsride: Make sure you use BASH. See with working demo: http://ideone.com/ePzOxq

Comment: Variation that doesn't require the separate `eol` definition is to replace `$eol` with a literal newline (as in, hit Enter, and the final `}"` appears at the beginning of the next line). Not as clear, but useful for code golf. The `"` around it are mandatory though, even if nothing else in the string would require them (since the newlines will get turned back into spaces in most [all?] contexts if it's not quoted).

Comment: Another way to avoid defining `eol`  would be to move $'...' into the curly brackets: `line="${line//@@ /$'\n'}"`. It works in my terminal, eg: `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"` prints all dirs from my `PATH` line by line.

Comment: Yes @saulius2 that should work for sure

Answer (score 12):

This will work

```
sed 's/@@ /\n/g' filename
```

replaces `@@` with new line

Comment: @rpax **thanks for editing** forgot to format my answer

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, this is a good answer. I like it. +1

Comment: You don't have to escape the first `@`, and this is missing a space after `@@`.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using the [tr](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr%201) function

```
echo "$line" | tr '@@' '\n'
```

For example:

```
[itzhaki@local ~]$ X="Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4@@ Value5|Value6|Value7|Value8@@"
[itzhaki@local ~]$ X=`echo "$X" | tr '@@' '\n'`
[itzhaki@local ~]$ echo "$X"
Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4

 Value5|Value6|Value7|Value8
```

Comment: This did not work in my script, it still has the '@@ ' in the output: `echo $x | tr '@@ ' '\n' >> $OUTPUT`

Comment: I know for a fact it works. I'm using "tr" all the time. Make sure you're using BASH and not SH, and that you're looking at the right output. Here, run this: http://pastebin.com/gxvKUwS9

Comment: As far as I know, tr works on individual characters, not strings.  As in, `tr 'Ab' 'aB'` turns `Abracadabra` into `aBracadaBra`.

Comment: You can replace `@@` to `@` before use `tr`: `echo "1@@2@@3" | sed 's/@@/@/g' | tr '@' '\n'`

Comment: You just need to "squeeze": `tr -s '@' '\n'`

Comment: The question asks to replace `@@` *plus a blank*, though. `tr` can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it working with:

```
sed 's/@@ /'\\\n'/g'
```

Adding the single quotes around \\n seemed to help for whatever reason

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind to use perl:

```
echo $line | perl -pe 's/@@/\n/g'
Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4
 Value5|Value6|Value7|Value8
 Value9|etc
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for line in `echo $longline | sed 's/@@/\n/g'` ; do
    $operation1 $line
    $operation2 $line
    ...
    $operationN $line
    for field in `echo $each | sed 's/|/\n/g'` ; do
        $operationF1 $field
        $operationF2 $field
        ...
        $operationFN $field
    done
done
```

Comment: Edited answer to make solution compatible with performing operations on both rows and fields in those rows.

Answer (score 0):

This wraps up using perl to do it, and gives some simple help.

```
$ echo "hi\nthere"
hi
there

$ echo "hi\nthere" | replace_string.sh e
hi
th
re

$ echo "hi\nthere" | replace_string.sh hi


there

$ echo "hi\nthere" | replace_string.sh hi bye
bye
there

$ echo "hi\nthere" | replace_string.sh e super all
hi
thsuperrsuper
```

#### replace_string.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ME=$(basename $0)
function show_help()
{
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

  replaces a string with a new line, or any other string, 
  first occurrence by default, globally if "all" passed in

  usage: $ME SEARCH_FOR {REPLACE_WITH} {ALL}

  e.g. 

  $ME :       -> replaces first instance of ":" with a new line
  $ME : b     -> replaces first instance of ":" with "b"
  $ME a b all -> replaces ALL instances of "a" with "b"
  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

STRING="$1"
TIMES=${3:-""}
WITH=${2:-"\n"}

if [ "$TIMES" == "all" ]
then
  TIMES="g"
else
  TIMES=""
fi

perl -pe "s/$STRING/$WITH/$TIMES"
```