# how to find a specific character combination and add a newline

Tags: sed

I have a large file that looks like this

`(something,something1,something2),(something,something1,something2)`

how do I use sed and find `),(` and replace it with `);(` or add a newline between the parentheses that has a comma character.

I did try `sed 's/),(/),\n(/g' filename.txt` but for some reason it does not work

Comment: How did it fail when you tried it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to **show at least the research effort** you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: If you have read any manual or tutorial on sed, this should be pretty much the first thing you learn how to do. So that is a good indication that you did not take the first step in solving this yourself.

Comment: [How to replace a pattern with newline (\n) with sed under UNIX / Linux operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940591/3776858) or [How do I replace a string with a newline using a bash script and sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23522132/3776858) or [How do I replace : characters with newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16565487/3776858) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace a string with a newline using a bash script and sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522132/how-do-i-replace-a-string-with-a-newline-using-a-bash-script-and-sed)

Comment: yeah, I did look that up and I am not that good at regEx. The command I have tried is sed 's/),(/),\n//g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who come here and want to know how this work without getting a lot of stackoverflow "greetings"

since I was on Mac os x you need to replace your `\n` with `\'$'\n''`
so to find `),(` and add a new line between the parentheses  this is the command I used 
`sed 's/;/\'$'\n''/g' testdone.txt > testdone2.txt`

ES

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "(something,something1,something2),(something,something1,something2)" | sed "s|),(|);(|"
```

This prints the below for me.

```
(something,something1,something2);(something,something1,something2)
```

For new line

```
echo "(something,something1,something2),(something,something1,something2)" | sed "s|),(|)\n(|"
```

And the above prints the below.

```
(something,something1,something2)
(something,something1,something2)
```